# How to display white background overflow on dropdown menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, overflow, z-index

I have a drop down menu created purely with CSS. I would like to implement an overflow using z-index (i presume) that will bleed over a border on my menu to give the impression that both the link and the dropdown menu are joined.

The drop down works correctly but I need the first menu item to overflow it's white background on to the drop down menu.

If you go to http://cssdesk.com/ztK64 and hover over the first menu link you will see what I am attempting to explain.

This is my code:

CSS

```
    /*Main nav*/
.main_nav_container{
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
    float:right;
}
ul.main_nav{
    margin:0;
    z-index:1;
    postion:absolute;
}
ul.main_nav li{
    margin:0;
    display:inline-block;
    border-top:solid 1px transparent;
    border-left:solid 1px transparent;
    border-right:solid 1px transparent;
}
ul.main_nav li a{  
    font-size:13px;
    display:block;
    font-weight:bold;
    height:25px;
    line-height:25px;
    padding:0 13px;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#1122cc;
    border:1px solid transparent;
}
ul.main_nav li a:hover{
  text-decoration:underline;
}
ul.main_nav li:hover{
    border-top:solid 1px #ccc;
    border-left:solid 1px #ccc;
    border-right:solid 1px #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:  4px 4px 0 0;
    -khtml-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    background: #fff;
} 
ul.main_nav li:hover ul{
    display:inline;
}
ul.main_nav li ul{
    display:none;
    z-index:500;
    position:absolute;
    background: #fff;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:solid 1px #ccc;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
    border-radius: 0 4px 4px 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius:  0 4px 4px 4px;
    -khtml-border-radius:  0 4px 4px 4px;
}
ul.main_nav li ul li{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:left;
}
ul.main_nav li ul li:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    border-top:solid 1px #fff;
    border-left:solid 1px #fff;
    border-right:solid 1px #fff;
}
ul.main_nav li ul li a{
    font-weight:normal;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="main_nav_container">
                <ul class="main_nav">
                <li>
                <a id="hover" href="#">For sale</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Property for sale</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">New homes for sale</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Find estate agents</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>


                <li><a href="#">To rent</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">New homes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">House prices</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Property advice</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: Is this problem fixed? I don't see a problem on your example page - drop down menu is white.

Comment: @MyHeadHurts, no, it isn't fixed in the question/example. The OP is wanting the menu to appear to be connected to the submenu (menu's background should overlap submenu's border). If you go to the example, and plug in the CSS from my answer below, you'll see what he means :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the following CSS:

```
ul.main_nav li:hover a {
 border-bottom:1px solid white;
 position:relative;
 z-index:100;
}
ul.main_nav li:hover ul {
 margin-top:-1px;
 margin-left:-1px;
 z-index:99;
}
```

You have to have the `position:relative;` in the `a` to make the `z-index` work correctly. The bottom border of the `a` is to cover up the border of the `ul`. The margin changes in the `ul` are to position the borders correctly for the effect of them being connected.